# ¿Como cargar Class par apoder usarla en toda la aplicacion android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, android-volley

Hola necesito ayuda para saber como cargar datos a una class desde dentro de un onResponse del StringRequest para luego utilizar esa clase en otras funciones dentro de la musma activity.
porque lo cargo pero cuando lo vou a utilizar fuera del StringRequest  en otra funcion me sale que el objeto es null

```
public class OrdenTrabajoForm extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView tvId; 
    OrdenTrabajo ojOT; //class
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    cargarOt("1"); //ejecutar cargarDatos pasandole el codigo de registro que deseo tener'
    tvId.setText(ojOT.getId().toString()); //me tira error null pero los datos fueron cargados en "cargarOt()"'
}
```

```
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject trab = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            //ojOT es una class inicializada antes del protected void onCreate

                            ojOT = new OrdenTrabajo( // aca es cargadfo pero saliendo del onResponse aparece comp nulo
                                    trab.getInt("id"),
                                    trab.getInt("nro_ot"),
                                    trab.getInt("tramite")
                            );
```

Comment: Entiendo que la función `cargarOT` hace sus cosas y añade el listener para la función `onResponse`. Pero dado que `onResponse` es asíncrona, no se ejecuta en el momento de crear el listener, sino cuando se produce el evento. Así que pasar por la función `cargarOT` no hace que crees el objeto que seguirá a `null` antes de terminar `onCreate`. Tienes que sacar de `onCreate` esa llamada y hacerla solo cuando ha terminado el `onResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que el error esta en que tvID nunca se le es asignado un valor y que el error de null se refiere a la variable tvID y no a ojOT.

En cuyo caso, solo debes decirle a tvID a que TextView corresponde, asi:

```
tvID=findViewById(R.id./*ID del TextView en el xml del layout*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas declarando pero no inicializando por eso arroja null. En ese punto de tu app aún la variable tvId no ha recibido el objeto al que apuntará